# lodash imported multiple times

Tags: javascript, webpack, lodash

So I analyzed my bundle and I noticed this.

[image]

You can see that lodash, lodash.min.js and all of the individual lodash functions are in my node_modules.

Throughout my app I have explicitly included lodash functions like so

```
import map from "lodash/map";
```

Why is the above happening? How do I prevent this?